# Android - How to detect parent layout type

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm using the following code:

```
        String[] UIItems = new String[5];
        UIItems[0] = "game_area_holder";
        UIItems[1] = "topListBtn";
        UIItems[2] = "bigBtn";
        UIItems[3] = "reposBtn";
        UIItems[4] = "sectorStateColorLine";
        for (int number = 0; number < UIItems.length; number++) {
            itemID = getResources().getIdentifier(UIItems[number],"id",getPackageName());

            ImageView aktUIItem = (ImageView) findViewById(itemID);

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams aktUIItemParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)aktUIItem.getLayoutParams();
 .
 . doing things here with aktUIItemParams
 .
 }
```

This works fine, but if I place one of the images into another Layout (Linear-, Relative-, etc.) then I get an error message:

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

Of course, it's because the parent is not a FrameLayout... But how can I check an image's parent's layout type programmatically? Or how can I cast getLayoutParams() into a "standard" LayoutParams?

Comment: "Or how can I cast getLayoutParams() into a "standard" LayoutParams?" [`ViewGroup.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) ?

Comment: It's almost good, but if I use ViewGroup.LayoutParams, then aktUIItemParams.leftMargin isn't available... :(
(Sorry, I did'nt write earlier... I need access to getIntrinsicWidth() and ...Height() and also the item leftMargin and topMargin properties)

Comment: I understand you already have an accepted answer, but there is a possibility [`ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) will contain all the methods/fields you need. If it does, then you would be able to avoid any casting.

Comment: Oooh, yeah, it's really better approach than the accepted... Sorry, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` wont work for ya then you will need to to an `instanceof` check to see if the layout params are of a type you can consume:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = aktUIItem.getLayoutParams();

if (layoutParams instanceof FrameLayout.LayoutParams) {
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)layoutParams;
  ...// do that old school logic
}
// ignore layoutParams or do another instance of check.
```

I would recomend you look through the subclasses (direct and indirect) that are listed in the google docs PPartisan linked ([here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)) to determine which subclasses offer the method you need to call. Then call the most super class that still has the method you need. That way you minimize the number of instanceof checks you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to change layout margin without knowing the parent, the solutions was this following

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) containerLayout.getLayoutParams();
        lp.setMargins(0, 0,0, Helper.getDPI(8,context));
        containerLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```